# YouTube, onPlayerReady, use for loop to get the Video ID in the array that matches the click arrow position and play

Tags: javascript, for-loop, youtube, youtube-api

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inkedraskal/cyhyjht5/3/

In the fiddle you'll see that you can play and pause individual videos by clicking on the them (play one, if you click on another it will stop that current video and play what you clicked on).

What i can't figure out is how to get the custom play button to work.  I have following for loop in the fiddle, but I'm guessing on click its not matching up the placement in the array.  If i'm clicking the 3rd "play" span, it should be playing the 3rd video:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    // if (players[i].getVideoUrl() != temp) players[i].stopVideo();

    for (var q = 0; q < ytPlayButtons.length; q++) {
      playButton = document.getElementById(ytPlayButtons[q]);
      playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(playButton);
        players[i].playVideo();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have edited you fiddle and remake the onPlayerReady() function:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gasp10/cyhyjht5/13/)

there the new code:

```
var videoCount = 1;
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  $("#play-"+videoCount).on("click", function() {
    console.log("play-"+videoCount);
    event.target.playVideo();
  });
  videoCount++;
}
```

this is the easy way to do.
you should take the id of the video and than link it to the button in some way.

The problem with your initial code is that `event.target` contains a single video and the function loop all the video in page, so you don't need to write more cycle inside.

from [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) you can use even this function to works with videos:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
}
```

than ytplayer will have the same property of event.target and you have the videoID for free to use

Comment: This is awesome, and thank for explaining it as well